# How to select multiple different CSS selectors with same base condition

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to select some elements on my page based on some conditions... and these all have some common parents as follow:

```
$("[id*=wizard_person]:not(.hidden) select.required, [id*=wizard_person]:not(.hidden) input.required:not(.tt-hint)").each ->
    ...
```

Here, I'm selecting both `input.required:not(.tt-hint)` and `select.required` that are present in `[id*=wizard_person]:not(.hidden)`.

However, I'm writing `[id*=wizard_person]:not(.hidden)` twice, to handle both scenarios.

Is there a way I can DRY this up? if yes, How? thanks.

Comment: can you try like this `$("select.required,input.required:not(.tt-hint) , [id*=wizard_person]:not(.hidden)")`

Comment: Why would you want to target `[id*=wizard_person]:not(.hidden)`? The OP is trying to target specific `input` and `select` descendants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start from `[id*=wizard_person]:not(.hidden)` and then find the correct descendants:

`$("[id*=wizard_person]:not(.hidden)").find("select.required, input.required:not(.tt-hint)").each(...)`

If your selects and inputs are direct children, you could even use `children()` instead of `find()`

Comment: awesomely neat and precise, what I wanted.